# Error with Objective-C code or me?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm new to the Objective-C code but I'm trying to learn from my book, "Head First iPhone Development", and I'm having a few problems with my "*decisionText;" in the .m file.

```
@synthesize decisionText;
no declaration of property 'decisionText' found in the interface
```

So whats wrong with the code? The version Im using is Xcode3 with Snow Lepord (10.6.8).
Am I missing something?

Comment: At this stage of XCode product development the answer to the "who's wrong" question is almost always "it's you". One does not need to read the entire question :)

Comment: You should learn what it is that @synthesize does -- it generates the implementation of so-called accessor methods for a given property. The problem here (as described in multiple answers below) is that you didn't declare the property in your interface.

Comment: You should check (tick) the answer that you feel best answers your question to reward the answerer appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

No offense, but probably the problem with you, not with Objective-C. You need to declare a matching property in the .h file (AKA in the interface).

For example:

```
@property (retain) NSString* decisionText;
```

Comment: The property declaration is often in the header file, but it can also be in a class extension in the implementation file.

Comment: Much thanks! ^_^ i was playing around and thought what could it hurt to change the code and i did and it works now! im just a stupid kid, what can i say?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `@synthesize decisionText;` in the implementation of a class:

```
@implementation MyClass
//...
@synthesize decisionText;
//...
```

Find the corresponding interface declaration (in the .h or .m file) and add:

```
@interface MyClass
//...
@property DecisionTextType *decisionText;
//...
```

where `DecisionTextType` is the type of `decisionText`, probably `NSString`.